# Android Observable Queries not working after adding suspend word

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

I am trying to migrate from `LiveData` to Kotlin `Flow`. Right now I am working on a project that has offline supports in `Room`.

I was looking through the documentation and I managed to write an observable query in coroutines with `Flow`. (see: [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries#observable))

The problem that I am facing right now is that whenever I add the suspend keyword inside the `DAO` class and try to run the project, it fails with the following error:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<MyModel>).
```

The code with the problem:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = :status LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getWithSpecificStatus(status: String): Flow<MyModel?>
```

I am calling the code like this:

```
val modelLiveData: LiveData<MyModel?> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val result = databaseService.getWithSpecificStatus(Enum.IN_PROGRESS.status).first()

        result?.let {
            emit(it)
        }

    }
```

I tried to keep things simple. why is my code failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly initialise the value of modelLiveData as:

```
    val modelLiveData=databaseService.
    getWithSpecificStatus(Enum.IN_PROGRESS.status).first()
    .asLiveData()
```

You have used Flow so `asLiveData()` is used to convert it to LiveData

Also suggestion , you do should not use the suspend keyword because when you are returning Flow, Room automatically does this asynchronously. You just need to consume the Flow.

Comment: So if I use .asLiveData(Dispatchers.IO) and delete the suspend keyword, this will run asynchronously?

Comment: It definitely will work. Also drop the Context (Dispatchers.IO), it is not required